# Virtmanager fails to create firewall rules: Extension REJECT revision 0 not supported

Tags: virtualization, nixos

I'm having trouble creating a functional vm environment on NixOS. When creating a new VM in Virtmanager, starting the network fails:

```
Could not start virtual network 'default': internal error: Failed to apply firewall rules [nix-store-id]/bin/iptables -w --table filter --insert LIBVIRT_FWO --in-interface virbr0 --jump REJECT: Warning: Extension REJECT revision 0 not supported, missing kernel module? iptables v1.8.8 (nf_tables): RULE_INSERT failed (No such file or directory): rule in chain LIBVIRT_FWO
```

To setup Virtmanager I added this to my Nix config:

```
virtualisation.libvirtd.enable = true;
programs.dconf.enable = true;
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [ virt-manager ];
trustedInterfaces = [ "virbr0" ];
users.users.miu.extraGroups = [ "libvirtd" ];
```

Virtmanager runs and it does connect to qemu/kvm. When creating a new VM however the error above appears.

- I'm on the Xanmod kernel at the moment but switching to Linux default made no difference.
- Disabling the NixOS firewall made no difference.
- Running `iptables -w --table filter --insert LIBVIRT_FWO --in-interface virbr0 --jump REJECT`in a terminal returns the same error from above.

I've tried the [NixOS forums](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/cant-start-virtual-network-in-virtmanager/20714) but no one there seemed to know what was causing it or how to resolve it. I'm hoping I'll have better luck here. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably not helping you much, but I have a similar issue running a docker container in WSL and my interpretation is that the available kernel doesn't support the specific iptables functionality we are attempting to use. My problem went away when I was running the container under native Linux.